# Wrong DNS resolution of FQDN LAN server

Tags: networking, server, dns, systemd-resolved

I have a server connected to my LAN and the Internet that I am unable to connect to using its FQDN.  Let's say the FQDN is `server.com`.

For whatever reason I have not been able to get to the bottom of, resolution of `server.com` on my development machine (locally on the LAN) always results in `::1`.

Here is the result of running `host -v server.com`:

```
Trying "server.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 39898
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
server.com.     6826    IN  A   192.168.0.2

Received 47 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 0 ms
Trying "server.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16204
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server.com.            IN  AAAA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
server.com.     6826    IN  AAAA    ::1

Received 59 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 0 ms
Trying "server.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48845
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;server.com.            IN  MX

Received 31 bytes from 127.0.0.53#53 in 0 ms
```

Notice the answer to the second question above.

`systemd-resolve` actually produces the correct answer:

```
$ systemd-resolve server.com
server.com: 192.168.0.2

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 3.3ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

I have tried to restart `systemd-resolved` as well as `--flush-caches` but to no avail.

`/etc/resolv.conf` contains the following:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search server.com
```

The DNS resolution is as given (resolution is served by `server.com`):
    $ nmcli device show enp0s31f6 | grep -n2 IP4.DNS
    10-IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.0.1
    11-IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
    12:IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.0.2
    13-IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          server.com
    14-IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9e5c:8eff:fe86:f30b/64

Finally, `systemd-resolve --status` produces the following:

```
Global
          DNS Domain: server.com
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.2
          DNS Domain: server.com
```

I should probably mention that the following services are active on the server (`server.com`): DHCP, DNS (bind9, IIRC), SSH, HTTP(s); it acts as the DNS resolver for all machines on the LAN. Lastly, I'm aware I could simply add an entry in `/etc/hosts` and be done with it but I would really like to understand what's wrong as it may be a symptom of something more serious with the.

How can I diagnose what's going on?

Comment: Do you know what DNS server is being used on the machine that `host` is being run on?  It sounds like it's querying its DNS server and perhaps that DNS server is authoritative and providing the wrong zone.  (Real life examples of this, however, would be prudent, if possible, because you're basically talking hypothetically the way this is currently worded)

Comment: @ThomasWard: this is not hypothetical; it's very much real. Unfortunately I cannot reveal the real server FQDN for legal reasons.  I've edited the post with additional info that I think answers your question?

Comment: Real or not, you missed the point of that statement.  And no, that doesn't answer what I"m after.  What I'm seeing there is it's handing to `systemd-resolve` which has a local component.  I'm looking for the servers that `systemd-resolve` is trying to reach out to for resolutions - is it checking a local `bind9` instance on the same server or querying some *other* DNS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by querying the server's DNS records, which produced the following:

```
$ host server.com
server.com has address 192.168.0.2
server.com has IPv6 address ::1
```

Inspecting the contents of bind9's `db.server.com` configuration file revealed a sneaky IPv6 entry:

```
@       IN  AAAA    ::1
```

Disabling the above and restarting bind9, solved it.

Thanks to Thomas Ward for comments that allowed me to approach this differently and eventually fix it.